# React: passing parameters to a function in map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, parameters, map-function

I am building a component that shows array of users in React using MaterialDesign's Table.

[image: Users Table]
 Each row is generated by a map function:

```
let actions = this.props.rowButtons;
...
{this.props.tableData.map( (val, index) => (
                       <TableRow key={index}>
                         <TableRowColumn >{index}</TableRowColumn>
                         <TableRowColumn >{val.firstName}</TableRowColumn>
                         <TableRowColumn >{val.lastName}</TableRowColumn>
                         <TableRowColumn >{val.email}</TableRowColumn>
                         <TableRowColumn >
                            <ActionButtons actions={actions}/>
                         </TableRowColumn>
                       </TableRow>
))}
```

`<ActionButtons>` component creates one or many buttons, and as an argument takes array of objects like `[{type: string, onClick: function}, {type: string, onClick: function}, ... ]` (one button for each object in array);
Parent component is sending such an array in **this.props.rowButtons**.

I want to pass **val**  as an argument to each onClick function to have something like

```
actions = [{type: "personButton", onClick: onClick(val)}, {type: '', onclick: someOtherfunction(val)}];
```

Comment: Try `onClick: () => onClick(val)`.

Comment: I dont quite understand. I assign array of objects to 'actions'. And I want to Inject val to each function  in this array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to modify the `actions` a bit. Try doing it following way.

```
modifyActions = (actions, val) => {
  return actions.map((a) => {
      return Object.assign({}, a, {onClick: () => a.onClick(val)})
  })
}

<ActionButtons actions={this.modifyActions(actions, val)})}/>
```